# How to make 1,293.34 become 129.33 in textview on android?

Tags: java, android

Is there a method that make the number that inside the `textview` like examples below?

```
input > output:

123.23 -> 12.32

4,593.78 -> 459.37
```

*It is a backspace function like the calculator button the number is backwards ( delete the last digit and move the decimal forwards*

I juz try sample code like this

```
// Get edit text characters
String textInBox = atmdisplay.getText().toString();
if(textInBox.length() > 0)
{
    //Remove last character//
    String newText = textInBox.substring(0, textInBox.length()-1);
    // Update edit text
    atmdisplay.setText(newText);
}
            }
```

it only delete the whole digit starting at last digit one by one.

Comment: divide by 10 and use number formatting upto 2 digits after decimal

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take the input as `double` value. Then divide from `10` and format the result.

Eg:

```
 double val = 4593.78 ;
 double result = val / 10;
 DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
 df.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.DOWN);
 System.out.println(df.format(result));
```

Out put:

```
 459.37
```

Comment: It will output as `12.32` and `459.38`. Actually the last one wanted as `459.37`.

Comment: @BatuhanC Ok. check my edited solution. It has address that too.

Answer (score 0):

No, as far as your question goes there is no such method inside TextView. You can create your own method to do it, something like:

```
public String roundOff(float value){
    long factor = (long) Math.pow(10, 2);
    value = value * factor;
    long temp = Math.round(value);
    double result = (double) temp / factor;
    return ""+result;
}
```

Here's how you can then use the method -> textView.setText(roundOff(123.23));

Answer (score 0):

This converts your edittext value to double:

```
double oldValue = 0.0;
String textInBox = atmdisplay.getText().toString();
if(!textInBox == null || !textInBox.isEmpty())
    oldValue = Double.parseDouble(textInBox );
```

Then with using Ruchira's solution:

```
double newValue = oldValue / 10;
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
df.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.DOWN);
atmdisplay.setText(df.format(newValue));
```

Answer (score -2):

You can simply divide by 10, since u only want two decimal point. then * 100 , round it then divide it :)

```
double d=123.23;
d=d/10;
double out=  (double) Math.round(d*100) / 100;
System.out.println(out);
```

Comment: This will not compile at least. What are you going to do actually? 
`Math.round()` will return a `long` value. Please try your code by your own before posting here.

Comment: Don't behave like a child here. Act like a professional. Your comment not constructive.

Comment: `stackoverflow` is a professional community. It is not a facebook kind of Dump. And your answer still wrong.

Comment: OP wants `4593.78>>459.37` But this will gives `459.38`

Comment: @nafas, it's not about him being happy, it's about helping others. If you rush in posting code that doesn't compile because you didn't check it, you're actually making things worse for the person asking the question. Anyone can make typos in answers, but when corrected, I usually give thanks to the person correcting me instead of mocking him/her. Further thoughts on the subject : http://stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice

Comment: @RuchiraGayanRanaweera Soz bro, I didn't mean to be rude, honestly speaking not in million years I thought what I said was offensive in anyway. hope everything is cool with u now.